# Casting to Interface (Dynamic casting at runtime)

Tags: c#, class, generics, interface

I have 3 classes Media,Image, Info. All three classes contain List of files implementing IResourceModel interface. These Media, Image & InfoFile are serialized and added to a Dictionary. I am looping on Dictionary, at runtime how can I cast these objects (Media, Image & InfoFile) to IResourceModel and fetch Files property.

```
public interface IResourceModel<T>  {
    T Files { get; set; }
}

class Media : IResourceModel<MediaFiles>
{
   public MediaFiles Files { get; set; }
}

class Image : IResourceModel<ImagesFiles>
{
   public ImagesFiles Files{ get; set; }
}

class InfoFiles : IResourceModel<InfoFiles>
{
   public InfoFiles Files{ get; set; }
}

Dictionary<ResourceType, object> resourcesList = new Dictionary<ResourceType, object> {
                    { ResourceType.Media,Media},
                    { ResourceType.Image,Image},
                    { ResourceType.InfoFiles , InfoFile}
};
```

Comment: The trouble is that ImageFiles, InfoFiles, and MediaFiles are not related from  what I see.  Do they share a common interface or base class?

Comment: yes ImageFiles, InfoFiles and MediaFiles  contains two similar property
1) FileId
2) Hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your type hierarchy is that there is no `IResourceModel`. There is only a `IResourceModel<T>` where `T` is of a concrete type. With generic types, `IResourceModel<A>` and `IResourceModel<B>` are two discrete types for any different type argument `A` and `B`, that actually share nothing except the similar name. So you simply cannot cast `Media`, `Image` and `InfoFiles` into a common type (other than object) because there is no common type.

This is usually solved by introducing another non-generic type that is additionally implemented. For example, types implementing `IEnumerable<T>` also implement a non-generic `IEnumerable` to allow a non-generic iteration.

So your type hierarchy could look like this:

```
public interface IResourceModel
{
    IFiles Files { get; }
}
public interface IResourceModel<T> : IResourceModel
{
    new T Files { get; set; }
}

public class Media : IResourceModel<MediaFiles>
{
    public MediaFiles Files { get; set; }
    IFiles IResourceModel.Files => Files;
}
public class Image : IResourceModel<ImagesFiles>
{
    public ImagesFiles Files { get; set; }
    IFiles IResourceModel.Files => Files;
}
public class Info : IResourceModel<InfoFiles>
{
    public InfoFiles Files { get; set; }
    IFiles IResourceModel.Files => Files;
}

public interface IFiles {}
public class MediaFiles : IFiles { }
public class ImagesFiles : IFiles { }
public class InfoFiles : IFiles { }
```

Now you could cast your types into `IResourceModel` and access the `Files` property to iterate over all `IFiles`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define a comment interface / class for you `ImageFiles`, `InfoFiles` and `MediaFiles`. Once example below.

```
interface IFiles
{
    string myField { get; set; }
    int myHash { get; set; }
}

class MediaFiles : IFiles
{
    public string myField { get; set; }
    public int myHash { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can iterate your dictionary by something like the following

```
Dictionary<ResourceType, IResourceModel<IFiles>> resourcesList = new Dictionary<ResourceType, IResourceModel<IFiles>> {
    { ResourceType.Media, new Media {Files = new MediaFiles {myHash = 20203, myField = "MediaFiles"} } }
};

foreach (KeyValuePair<ResourceType, IResourceModel<IFiles>> entry in resourcesList)
{
    var files = entry.Value.Files;
    var field = files.myField;
    var hash = files.myHash;
}
```

---

**Edit**

Theoretically you can use `dynamic` instead of `object` to access what you want, i.e. `File`. But I would always do something like the above, to always have strong types enforced.

---

**Edit 2**

To cast generic interface, another interface implementation is needed.

```
public class Media : IResourceModel<MediaFiles>, IResourceModel<IFiles>
{
    public MediaFiles Files { get; set; }
    IFiles IResourceModel<IFiles>.Files
    {
        get { return Files; }
        set { Files = (MediaFiles)value; } // <--- Cautious! Check type in production code.
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 3**

Rethink of the fundamental problem you met, i.e. Why would you want a dictionary `resourcesList`? i.e. shouldn't your resource give you the type it belongs to, rather than you keep a mapping for them? This drives me to give the following complete re-implementation.

- `ResourceType` is a property of `Files`.

Firstly, what you want to achieve at the end

```
var listOfFiles = new List<IFiles> // <-- List rather than Dictionary
{
    new ImagesFiles(
        new List<ImagesFile>
        {
            new ImagesFile {path = "C:\\wf.n"},
            new ImagesFile {path = "C:\\wfz.n"}
        }
    ),
    new MediaFiles(
        new List<MediaFile>
        {
            new MediaFile {path = "C:\\wf.jpg", foo = 1},
            new MediaFile {path = "C:\\wfz.png", foo = 2}
        }
    )
};

foreach (var files in listOfFiles)
{
    Console.WriteLine(files.resourceType); // <-- Gives Media / Image
    var fileshash = files.GetHashCode();
    foreach (IFile file in files.GetFiles())
    {
        var myPath = file.path;
        var hash = file.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**Interface definitions**

```
public interface IFile
{
    string path { get; set; } // <--- GetHashCode doesn't need to be in here.
}

public interface IFiles : IEnumerable<IFile>
{
    IEnumerable<IFile> GetFiles();
    ResourceType resourceType { get; } // <-- Getter only here on the interface
}

public interface IFiles<out T> : IFiles
    where T : IFile  // <-- This will enforce the same file type in this collection
{
    new IEnumerable<T> GetFiles();
}
```

**Class definitions**

```
public class ImageFile : IFile
{
    public string path { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return path.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class ImageFiles : IFiles<ImageFile>
{
    public ImageFiles(IEnumerable<ImageFile> files)
    {
        this.files = files.ToList();
    }
    public bool mySpecialProperty { get; set; } // <--- ImageFiles special, Not in Media nor Image

    public ResourceType resourceType => ResourceType.Image;

    private List<ImageFile> files;

    public IEnumerable<IFile> GetFiles()
    {
        return files;
    }

    IEnumerable<ImageFile> IFiles<ImageFile>.GetFiles()
    {
        return files;
    }

    public IEnumerator<IFile> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return files.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return files.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I same thing with Dynamics, please advise

Comment: If it's type `dynamic`, then you can straight ask for `Lists`. See edit 2 for your cast invalid problem. See edit 3 for a rethink of your problem.